# How to find the best collective midpoint between more than 2 points?

Tags: graphing-functions

If I have more than 2 points on a graph, how would I best find a point that might be the midpoint between all of them?

Comment: Independent of whether the points are on a graph, you can find what might be called their midpoint by forming the average of each of the coordinates.

Comment: @Theo: graph paper.

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks. I've just figured that out by the OP's reaction to Ross's answer :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a bunch of $n$ points, $(x_i,y_i)$, you can use $$(\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i,\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i)$$  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Oh of course! Thank You